# Interpret an chain of attributes combined via "and"/ "or" in english and other languages?

Tags: computational-linguistics, word-sense-disambiguation

The question is, what is the most correct way to interpret a chain of attributes, say of the noun but also possible of a verb, connected together with multiple and and or conjunction, in english or in any other language you suggest ( yes, i am gathering info about different languages)

Let me explain by example:

```
an angry brown and hungry bear
```

There is no ambiguity here - the last "and" has just the role of comma. Yes, if nothing else  is told, you interpret chain of attributes connected with "and", right?

Next example:

```
an angry brown or hungry bear
```

Now you must think longer what it exactly means, right?

What is the "most correct" way to disambiguate this statement, does it means this way:

```
(angry brown) or (hungry) bear
```

or `angry  and (brown or hungry)` bear or how?

In some cases you can gain information if attributes are mutual exclusive, this means they must be split apart by "or":

```
angry (brown or black) bear
```

But really complicated it get bigger chain with  "or" and "and" mixed like:

```
angry or fast and roaring or brown bear
```

So the question again, what is the most correct way to interpret these statements?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your question raises interesting issues about predicate logic, but not really about linguistics.  Your examples are not acceptable utterances in normal speech; and, many languages, especially outside of Europe, do not have words that are clean equivalents of "and" and "or."  For useful reliable answers, you should limit your question to how such conjunctions actually do work or search for a site than can offer a better discussion about predicate logic and its structural rules.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really about general linguistic topics, but about how predicate logic works in English.  It could be edited by focusing on the function of coordinating conjunctions or perhaps by asking an open question about cognitive linguistics and how confusing statements are resolved.